# Can Android XML input "@"?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I want to hard code a string resource with an email syntax like ABC@gmail.com.
But, eclipse pop up an error to say that "@" cannot be included.

How can '@' include in the string resource.

Thanks you.

Comment: Even encoding the @ as \u0040 does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add string in strings.xml:

```
<string name="email">xyz@gmail.com</string>
```

and try to set this in activity as:

```
textView.setText(R.string.email);
```